# Telerik WPF - Could not load type 'Telerik.Windows.Controls.TemplateVisualStateAttribute' from assembly 'Telerik.Windows.Controls,

Tags: wpf, telerik

Any ideas how I could resolve the following error?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Unknown build error, 'Could not load type
>   'Telerik.Windows.Controls.TemplateVisualStateAttribute' from assembly
>   'Telerik.Windows.Controls, Version=2017.2.614.45, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7'. Line 117 Position 350.'

Comment: If you could provide an example of the code you're using that would be very helpful

Comment: <telerik:RadScheduler Name="radSchedule" t

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like Telerik JustDecompile to open the dll file and see if loads properly from the folder.

It should tell you the missing file it there is any.

you can visit this site to download it

https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

Comment: I downloaded JustDecompile.. dragged the Telerik.Windows.Controls.. it opens... Then what?  thanks

Comment: Did you expand the dependencies tree on the left side? it should show error if it could not load any dependent dll.  Did you open if from the same folder from where you are running your application?